# Is there an input type which can take dates before 0 A.D?

Tags: html, forms, input, web-deployment

I'm making a history website for my college which take dates as input as old as 13,000 B.C and the < input type="date"> only accepts dates from 0 A.D. Is there any input type that takes dates from that long ago as input? Thanks in advance!

Comment: How about a textbox, `<input type="text" />`?

Comment: A date input is mostly supposed to make it easy for users to find a date using a calendar. I don't think that's terribly useful for BC dates. Not only would it take ages to click through to the calendar page of that year, dates also become more and more murky the farther back you go, and day-accuracy is pretty useless.